# HTTP Header Request

Tags: http, servlets, http-headers

I have looked through many sites but I have yet to find the answer to this question:

I have a login page and after the user logs in I want to redirect to a completely different URL. But while redirecting it I want to pass the username with the http request. So for example:

request.setHeader(“test”,“testing.request) and then from the server side they can retrieve the header by request.getHeader(“test”).

Comment: Are you looking for a generic explanation or language specific like JQuery etc?

Comment: in java `response.sendRedirect(String url);` and `RequestDispatcher` can be used.

Comment: Looking for what language should I use to do this. And sendRedirect(string url) doesn't pass the header along with the request. It completely redirects the request to a different URL. That's what I want but I also want the header to be passed with the request.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that with "redirect" you mean doing `response.sendRedirect(newURL);`. That means, that your login servlet, after a successful login, tells the **browser**, that it should send new request. The new request uses GET method, so the only way to add parameters is to add them directly to the new URL, e.g. `response.sendRedirect("http://your.server/new/location?username=johndoe");`.

If you want to use and modify the original request, I would suggest you to read http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=181 (Forward versus redirect).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not trying to set a parameter. I'm trying to set a hidden header with the http request.

Comment: Then you can't make a redirect, with redirect it is not possible to set header. You should probably try to use the `RequestDispatcher` and its `forward` method. See the link in my answer, and also http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-is-a-request-dispatcher-and-how-do-i-use-it.html might be useful.